# Java言語でBLE通信

Tags: java, bluetooth

初めての質問投稿です。皆様のお力をお貸しください。

Java言語を使ってiOS端末とBLE通信をしたいと考えています。
Java側（ペリフェラル） iOS側（セントラル）想定です。

色々調べているのですが、Java言語でペリフェラル側、アドバタイズに関する情報が
ほとんどなくて困っています。

Java言語を使ってBLE通信、アドバタイズさせるにはどうすれば良いでしょうか。

やりたいこと
・Java言語を使用してBLE通信
・Java側（ペリフェラル） iOS側（セントラル）
・java言語でアドバイタイズ

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: AndroidではなくデスクトップのJavaということでしょうか

Comment: Android以外のプラットフォームでJava+BLEは特殊という印象がありますが... ちなみにAndroidならサンプルはいろいろありそうです。 http://qiita.com/anzai_k/items/131373caa0a6294efdd4

Comment: Androidではなく、デスクトップなどのJavaで開発しようと考えています。

Answer (score 1):

[iOSでBluetooth通信](http://iot-jp.com/category/tutorial/ios%E3%81%A7bluetooth%E9%80%9A%E4%BF%A1)　に解説記事(８つに分かれている)がありますが、お読みになりましたか？

質問に書かれている事項について、一通り説明されているように思います。
例えば、アドバタイズについては「ペリフェラルが実行するタスク」の記事で解説されています。